# Macro to multicol section content but not section title

Tags: macros

```
\section{Introduction}
```

I want to write a macro to that makes the above behave the same as:

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{Introduction}]
```

In praise of code convolution avoidance:
The shortest and simplest answer(Most adhering to the KISS philosophy) will be the accepted answer. DON'T use a library if you don't NEED to.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want to write `\section{Introduction}` and have it be the same as `\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{Introduction}]`? Your directives about what answers are acceptable are ill-advised and frankly, kinda rude.

Comment: You should make it clear whether or not the matching `\end{multicols}` should also be handled automatically, because taking your request literally, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the best I could come up with. First, I define `\oldsection` as the old \section macro, then use it to define a new \section command which first ends the previous multicolumn environment, unless it's the first section, in which case it does nothing, and then starts a new multicolumn environment with a section heading as defined by old section.

I also have to redefine `\enddocument` to end the final multicolumn.

This is not a very robust or advisable solution, but may work in a pinch.

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand*{\section}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\thesection = 0}{}{\end{multicols}}%
    \begin{multicols}{2}[\oldsection{#1}]}
\let\oldend\enddocument
\renewcommand*{\enddocument}{\end{multicols}\oldend}
```

To used as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand*{\section}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\thesection = 0}{}{\end{multicols}}%
    \begin{multicols}{2}[\oldsection{#1}]}
\let\oldend\enddocument
\renewcommand*{\enddocument}{\end{multicols}\oldend}
\begin{document}
        \section{My first section}
        \lipsum[1-2]
        \section{Another section}
        \lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked almost like a charm!! If I could just figure out how to make those foot notes appear pretty and above sections following sections(on the same page); I would say this is worth adding to the multicol package as an option. But that would be another question.

Comment: This seems to break if you add `\tableofcontents`... also, I changed the ifthen to `\ifthenelse{\equal{\@currenvir}{multicols}}{\end{multicols}}{}` to specifically check if you're in a multicols before issuing \end, otherwise I got errors on a large document. Still working on the `\tableofcontents` issue though...

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your question, but this might do what you want:

```
\newenvironment{xmulticols}[1]{\section{#1} \begin{multicols}{2}}{\end{multicols}}
```

This would only work if you only ever wanted 2 column layout, but is easily fixable to more columns.

I'd also recommend you also change how the section headings look (maybe make them centered?) to make clear that the section heading "covers" both columns...

Comment: No, I think he wants to write only `\section{blah blah}` and have it behave this way.

Comment: Ah I see. I didn't think of that. I guess because I don't like the idea of having environments begin and end without the `\begin` and `\end` markers visible. I'm not sure it's a good idea...

Comment: Agreed. The whole thing makes me nervous. But I still, I like a challenge.